# Azure AD B2C ASP.NET redirect loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, owin, azure-ad-b2c

We've implemented Azure AD B2C in Umbraco on the front end using Microsofts webapp sample https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi

Most of the time this is generally working, but after a while everyone starts getting hit by a redirect loop. Restating the website then clears the issue.

It seems to be something causing the .AspNet.Cookies cookie to stop being set when the user is redirected back to the site with an id token.

Any ideas?

Comment: This might be due to the cookie policy. Can you confirm whether the following interactions are occurring? The user has browsed to a HTTP endpoint; the browser is redirected from this HTTP endpoint to Azure AD B2C; the token is issued from Azure AD B2C to a HTTPS endpoint at which a *HTTPS-only* cookie is created; the browser is returned from this HTTPS endpoint to the HTTP endpoint to which the user had browsed; then it starts over again.

Comment: No the user is going to an HTTPS endpoint and then redirected to Azure AD B2C and then redirected back to the HTTPS endpoint again.

At this point I'm not sure what logging I can actually put in place to see why they're not being validated. They have the cookie, but for some reason the validation of it seems to have stopped so they end in a loop.

Comment: Turn on preserve log in console and network in dev tools. There’s probably an error in the redirect URL that will shed some light 

Comment: No error in the reply url. I've added logging and the security token validated notification is being hit. Just no cookie set.

Comment: i am also facing the same issue, have to got any solution for this?

Comment: i enabled HTTPS only under TLS/SSL settings in web app and error resolved.

Answer (score 4):

In AD B2C `App Registration` section for the app, expects it to have a `RedirectURI` and I forgot to put `signin-oidc`

So changing:

```
https://localhost:5000
```

To

```
https://localhost:5000/signin-oidc
```

resolved my problem.

This is the default value - `/signin-oidc` - unless something else is explicitly set.

Answer (score 1):

I had infinite loop issue at logout and it was because of missing support of Razor pages. The default Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI SignOut action uses /Account/SignedOut Razor page as callback url.

```
var callbackUrl = Url.Page("/Account/SignedOut", pageHandler: null, values: null, protocol: Request.Scheme);
```

I added Razor support in my Asp.Net core web app and it fixed the issue.

```
 services.AddRazorPages();
```

and

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that your Reply URL in your application registration matches your Redirect URI in the web.config. Try setting both of these to your main homepage URL to ensure that your app is registered properly. Also make sure that the Application ID and the Client ID are matching and the right tenant is set in your web config. This needs to be the onmicrosoft.com tenant. Also, ensure that your users have the right permissions for the application.

Please follow the instructions in my blog and video to ensure that these are set properly. 
https://medium.com/@marilee.turscak/reply-urls-vs-postlogoutredirecturis-in-azure-active-directory-aad-20f57a03267b

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A9U1VGyztEM

You can also try deleting the application and republishing it. If none of these things work, it may actually be an issue with the platform itself.

Answer (score 0):

enabled HTTPS only under TLS/SSL settings in web app .

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was because I didn't have the scope defined in my b2c configuration settings, like this:

```
"Resources": {
    "myApi": {
        "ResourceUri": "https://localhost:44361",//"https://my.ui.com",
        "ResourceScopes": [
            "https://myapp.onmicrosoft.com/my-api/Admin.Read.Write" // this was wrong, which caused my looping
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting a logout redirect loop. It would actually log out, but just get stuck in a loop. In my case, the redirect URL I had configured in Azure was fine (I had `/signin-oidc`).

I followed the guide on adding my own account controller action rather than using the built in `MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignOut` (while also adding the `id_token` validation to secure the logout): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/enable-authentication-web-application-options#secure-your-logout-redirect

My startup.cs code is per the documentation, my controller code looks like this (the documentation code is missing `AuthenticationProperties` variable):

```
namespace Cosmos.WebPortal.Controllers;

[AllowAnonymous]
[Area("MicrosoftIdentity")]
[Route("[area]/[controller]/[action]")]
public class MyAccountController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("{scheme?}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SignOutAsync([FromRoute] string scheme)
    {
        scheme ??= OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

        var redirectUrl = Url.Content("~/");
        var properties = new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = redirectUrl };

        //obtain the id_token
        var idToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("id_token");
        //send the id_token value to the authentication middleware
        properties.Items["id_token_hint"] = idToken;

        return SignOut(properties, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, scheme);
    }
}
```

So my logout link is now to this controller instead e.g. 'MicrosoftIdentity/MyAccount/SignOut'

That seems to work fine, no infinite loop. A bit frustrating as I don't really understand the cause or difference, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was an expired secret/certificate in Azure B2C. It's important to look at the network log to see if any message, thankfully there was message telling me exactly where to look

Answer (score 0):

`Rebuild App Don't Do a Restart`

During a debug session, for me it was to rebuild the app instead of just attempting a run.

I was changing the config file and when I launched the app through Visual Studio, it wasn't rebuilding/restarting the app, hence it was continuously in the repeating call back cycle *from* the initial session failure.

Doing a `Clean` (or `Rebuild`) did the job and one of the chagned values  in the config (`.json`) file allowed it to properly login/redirect.