# .net 5 Azure b2c logout loop

Tags: c#, .net, azure, .net-core

Hello I'm trying to implement azure b2c in an app. Everything works fine logging in. But when I log out it get stuck in an infinite loop. All the examples I can find seem to be .net core 3.1.

Here is my appsettings.

```
"AzureAdB2C": {
"Instance": "https://xxx.b2clogin.com",
"TenantId": "xxx",
"ClientId": "xxx",
"Domain": "xxx.onmicrosoft.com",
"SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout/B2C_1_Normal",
"SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_Normal",
//"CallbackPath": "/signin/B2C_1_Normal"
}
```

Here is my startup.

```
 services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
 .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
 {
     Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options);
 }).EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new string[] { Configuration["ApiScope"] 
 })
 .AddInMemoryTokenCaches
services.AddControllersWithViews(options=>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
}).AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
```

To sign out, I just have a button click.

```
<a class="nav-link" asp-area="MicrosoftIdentity" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignOut">Sign out</a>
```

It does sign me out, but I'm stuck in a redirect loop back to my app, and then back to the B2C.

Comment: Those are built in to the MicrosoftIdentityUI package.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and it was because of missing support of Razor pages. The default Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI SignOut action uses /Account/SignedOut Razor page as callback url.

```
var callbackUrl = Url.Page("/Account/SignedOut", pageHandler: null, values: null, protocol: Request.Scheme);
```

I added Razor support in my Asp.Net core web app and it fixed the issue.

```
 services.AddRazorPages();
```

and

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
```

Alternatively you can use your own logout endpoint, which can use any action as signed out callback url.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to test in my local environment , and it was tested successfully with sign in and sign out from my webapplication using AzureAdB2C credentials.

Here are the steps that i followed:

Created a B2C tenant in Portal and link it to my subscription.

[image]

After linked created an **App registration** with selected as below and authenticate with id and access token .

[image]

[image]

I have added the **userflow** and select the following to configure:

[image]

Then in visual studio created an Asp.net core web application and provide the **domain and policy** details which i created in above

[image]

> Domain name - Azure AD B2C Overview tab  Application Id - From app
> registration overview tab Sign-up or sign-in policy - From user flows
> Overview

Copied the reply URI and paste in redirect URI section in portal

[image]

Here is my `appsettings.json` file

[image]

And it allows me to sign-in and after sign-out it redirect to my home page as well :

[image]

[image]

For more information please refer the below links:

.[How to sign out of Azure ADB2C |MS Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/264757/how-to-sign-out-of-azure-adb2c.html) .

.[Configure session behavior in Azure Active Directory B2C | MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior?pivots=b2c-user-flow)

Comment: Was your web application .Net 5? I have everything you do already so I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Ah, you used VS2017, so not .net 5

Comment: Yes i was trying with Vs 2017, Asp.net core webapp . 
 Could you please refer this [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/enable-authentication-web-application?tabs=visual-studio#step-6-add-the-app-settings) for your `appsettings.json`  .

Comment: I have it exactly as they do. Everything works minus I get a redirect loop on signout.

Comment: "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout/<your-sign-up-in-policy>",

 In this  code have you add your sign up-in policy as on

 "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "<your-sign-up-in-policy>" .  And also please refer this SO link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51268552/azure-ad-b2c-asp-net-redirect-loop

Comment: I've edited my initial post with the new app settings.